# laravel htaccess not working correctly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

i have a weird thing with the laravel framework .
apache can't read the .htaccess which is located in the public folder within the laravel framework .
here is the configuration file for the virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/zafaty/public
    ServerName  zafaty.dev
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/zafaty/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
        AllowOverride All
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the .htaccess file .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

also i tried this one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but it didn't work too .
i still can access the routes like this http://zafaty.dev/index.php/example but when tried to access normally http://zafaty.dev/example it gives 404 error
BTW im using linux mint nadia .

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark as I was having the same problem and this fixed it....

Make sure your httpd.conf has the following line:

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```